# Flat faces in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

On evee works. Shadesmooth is on. It looks that's broking my uv idk...

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what you are trying to do? It currently is very hard to understand what you are saying.

Comment: I was getting flat faces in some parts of the model. But it's because of the normal. The normal wasn't on non color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the normal map. Always use color space on non color...

Comment: Congrats on solving it, and thanks for sharing the solution :). Don't forget to later mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I  have to wait for 7 hours to do so....